# How should admin change the shipping method

Tags: e-commerce

I am developing an ecommerce store for a client. I am not sure how to go about handling the shipping methods.

Lets say that there are two shipping methods:

```
Ground shipping - $10
Express shipping - $30
```

Buyer comes and selects `Ground shipping`.

However before buyer hits the `checkout` button the admin changes the price of `ground shipping` to `$20`. Since buyer agreed to pay `$10` buyer should only pay `$10`.

Also for security reason when checkout is hit the order_id is sent to the server and the total price is recalculated. When this recalculation happens then shipping price has changed from $10 to $20. This is not good.

To solve this I have two thoughts.

1) When buyer selects`ground shipping` then clone all the attributes of the shipping to somewhere and now these values belong to order. This is less than ideal since shipping could get complicated with different shipping rates for domestic vs international etc. And cloning all those attributes might not be possible.

2) Do not allow admin to change and existing shipping method. Admin can only create new shipping method.

I tried to look at how other open source ecommerce applications handle it but could not get any meaningful information.

Answer (score 1):

Option #2 is what needs to happen. Allow the admin to change the existing shipping method only when the site is down for a scheduled maintenance so you are not changing anyone's pricing costs on them "behind their back" and also so that the customers know in advance the site is going down for maintenance and maybe in the maintenance message you can mention that shipping prices may be being updated during this downtime / maintenance period.

Changing the costs of shipping on a live site while people are making purchases and shopping is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

3) Log price changes with timestamps on server, so when recalculation is performed, the old (buyer checkout) price is calculated.